# Value of type 'Single' can't be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'

Tags: vb.net

```
For i = 0 To 2
        If Niz1(i) > Niz2(i) Then
            a = Niz1(i)
            b = Niz2(i)
            Call ZamjenaNiza(a, b)
            Niz1(i) = Prvi
            Niz2(i) = Drugi

        End If
    Next i
    For j = 0 To 3
        Me.DataGridView(j + 1, 1) = Niz1(j)
        Me.DataGridView(j + 1, 2) = Niz2(j)


    Next j

End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem? Can't find solution, not even on Visual Basic help page! It shows me error on this 2 code lines:

```
Me.DataGridView(j + 1, 1) = Niz1(j)
Me.DataGridView(j + 1, 2) = Niz2(j)
```

**It says** : Value of type 'Single' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'

Comment: `Value of type 'Single' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'` that is an obvious error. Have you tried debugging this? You are trying to set a value (Single) to an object of type `DataGridViewCell`... `Me.DataGridView(j + 1, 1)` will get you the `DataGridViewCell` object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to assign a `Single` value to a DataGridViewCell object, you should assign it to the `.Value` property of the object ..

```
Me.DataGridView(j + 1, 1).Value = Niz1(j)
```